# WPF change main window opacity only while secod window is close

Tags: c#, wpf, opacity

i have a WPF application with main window and second window that opened from main window button. i want the main window opacity to change while second window is open and when i will close it the opacity of the main window will back to defaut.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: i successed to change the main window opacity when i opened the second window but i dont know how to get back the opacity when i close the second window.

Comment: before you display the second window, subscribe to its Closing event from the main window. in that event handler set the opacity back to the original value.

Comment: How do you show the 2nd window?  As a Dialog or not?

Comment: Then you can simply change the properties just before and after the call to ShowDialog(). No need for any eventhandling.

Answer (score 1):

This is your first window's code to invoke the second window.

```
var newWindow = new Window1();
newWindow.ShowDialog();
```

You can add an event handler to `newWindow` to detect Window1's close.

```
var newWindow = new Window1();
Application.Current.MainWindow.Opacity = 0.5;
newWindow.Closed += (sender, e) =>
{
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Opacity = 1;
};


newWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: i want that main window (window1) will change the opacity while window2 is open. when i will close window2 , window1 will change the opacity back.i opened window2 as dialog. i didnt understand where to put the code above...sorry. the above code will open a new window1.. i dont want it.

Comment: Mark the above as answer if you found it useful and appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

got it....

```
    private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Opacity = 1;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Opacity = 1;
    }
```